# How do I code input layer in Deep Learning using Keras (Basic)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

Okay so I'm pretty new to deep learning and have a very basic doubt. I have an input data with an array containing 255 data (Araay shape (255,)) in epochs_data and their corresponding labels in new_labels (Array shape (255,)).

I split the data using the following code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(epochs_data, new_labels, test_size = 0.2, random_state=30)
```

I'm using a sequential model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
model = Sequential()
```

I know how to code for the hidden layers and output layer:

```
model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu')) #Hidden Layer
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax')) #Output Layer
```

But I don't know how to code layer for input with the input_shape specified. The X_train is the input.It's an array of shape (180,).  Also tell me how to code the model.fit() for the same. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why have you bolded all of your text?

Comment: I don't know xD Thought it would make it easier to read. I'll edit it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to copy this line before the hidden layer. You can add the activation function that you want. Finally, as you can see this line represent both the input layer and the 1° hidden layer (you have to choose the n° of neuron (I put 100) )

```
model.add(Dense(100, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],))
```

EDIT:
Before fitting your model you have to configure your model with this line:

```
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'Adam', metrics = ['mse'])
```

So you have to choose a metric that in this case is Mean Squarred Error and an optimizer like Adam, Adamax, ect.

Then you can fit your model choosing the data (X,Y), n° epochs, val_split and the batch size.

```
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 200,
                    validation_split = 0.1, batch_size=250)
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error. IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: I changed it to X_train[0] and it works. Can you tell me how to implement model.fit() for the same?

Comment: I've posted a follow up question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60226423/valueerror-error-when-checking-input-expected-dense-1-input-to-have-shape-180               I would really appreciate it if you could guide me